# Mac Pyinstaller App Does Not Open

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created an executable for Mac using `pyinstaller` but the app itself will not open, it starts and then quickly closes. Any ideas how to fix this error?

This is the command I ran to build the app:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed Music_Playing_App.py
```

Comment: There's probably a bug in your code that causes the app to crash

Comment: Is there anything in particular in the code I should look for?

Comment: try to run your code in the terminal with `python code.py` and see whether there are any errors. If there are none, there's probably something wrong with the imports: maybe `pyinstaller` failed to find some library you're using. Also, it should print some info while building the app, so read whatever it reports carefully.